# How to set default option selected?

Tags: javascript, jsp

In my code I'm using two dropdownlistbox. From the first DDL I have multiple array of values. If I select any one of the value and then click the button, the selected value is removed from the first DDL and added into the second DLL. All these processes are running properly.

But, how do I set the default selected option into the second DDL? This is my script:

```
function SelectMoveRows(SS1,SS2)
{
    var SelID='';
    var SelText='';
    var count=0;
    // Move rows from SS1 to SS2 from bottom to top
    for (i=SS1.options.length - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if (SS1.options[i].selected == true)
        {
            SelID=SS1.options[i].value;
            SelText=SS1.options[i].text;
            var newRow = new Option(SelText,SelID);           
            SS2.options[SS2.length]=newRow;            
            SS1.options[i]=null;
            //count++;//by raghu
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as the arguments for `new Option` are

```
new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected);
```

Did you try

```
var newRow = new Option(SelText,SelID, true, true);
```

Another option would be to set the selects value to the same as `SelID` after the option is inserted.

```
SS2.value = SelID;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response dear adeneo i will try